# To print any valid size for the fourth side to make a non-degenerate simple quadrilateral

Tags: c, math

I need to print any value that's valid to be the size of the fourth side of a quadrilateral whose other 3 sides are given.

Problem link: https://codeforces.com/contest/1422/problem/A

So below is my program for it but somehow the online judge won't accept it, giving me this for the test case#2

> "wrong answer : Maximum value no less than sum other values on 96"

Now the problem is I couldn't see the input 96 on test case#2 and thus don't understand what's the problem with my code. What should I do here?

```
#include<stdio.h>
 
long long int max(long long int x, long long int y);
 
int main()
{
    int t;
    scanf("%d", &t);
    while(t--)
    {
        long long int a,b,c, d, num;
        scanf("%llu %llu %llu", &a, &b, &c);
        num = max(a,max(b,c));
        printf("%llu\n", num+1);         //valid fourth side size - max(a,b,c) + 1

    }
    return 0;
}
 
long long int max(long long int x, long long int y)
{
    return (x > y) ? x : y;
}
```

[image: Here's a snap from the checker window]

---

I could solve it with some other valid values for the fourth side like a+b+c-1 but I think I need to know why is the above code failing.

Comment: From the linked problem page, for the 2nd trial example `12 34 56`, the given/correct solution, is `42`. But, `max(a,b,c)` is 56, and `56 - 1` isn't 42. So, I think you'll need a better algorithm. I'm not sure how to solve this, but, for the lengths `a`, `b`, and `c`, you _may_ need to pay attention to the order of the line segments (e.g.) `a b c d`, `a c b d`, `b a c d`, `b c a d`, `c a b d`, `c b a d`. Then, see which ones are valid. Also, if there is more than one valid solution, do you output each solution on separate lines, or do you put them on the same line?

Comment: Just a guess. You might have want to sort the lengths: `lo, mid, hi`. Then, look at the order: `lo, hi, mid, d`

Comment: `long long int` must be scanned with `%lld`, not `%llu`

Comment: @CraigEstey I need to print only one valid value for the fourth side (I know there could be multiple possible solutions) also `max(a,b,c) + 1` for the 2nd trial example is 57 (i.e. 56+1), which could be a solution so that's fine. And I don't understand why would I need to sort the lengths?